# Cut arrays to create table values from 0 to 5 then 6 to 11 etc

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, html-table

It's  hard to explain but here is my request:
Today I have a table generated with 4 arrays in PHP like that:

```html
@for ($counter_functions = 0; $counter_functions < count($my_array['functions']); $counter_functions++)
 <?php 
  $array_1 = $my_array['functions'][$counter_functions]['statistic']['first_data']['hours'];
  $array_2 = $my_array['functions'][$counter_functions]['statistic']['second_data']['hours'];
  $array_3 = $my_array['functions'][$counter_functions]['statistic']['third_data']['hours'];
  $array_4 = $my_array['functions'][$counter_functions]['statistic']['fourth_data']['hours'];
 ?>
 <table>
  <tr>
   <th></th>
   <?php 
    foreach ($array_1 as $key => $value) {
     echo '<th>'.$key.'</th>';
    }
   ?>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th>Number of connections</th>
   <?php 
    foreach ($array_1 as $key => $value) {
     echo '<th>'.$value.'</th>';
    }
   ?>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th>Number of successes</th>
   <?php 
    foreach ($array_2 as $key => $value) {
     echo '<th>'.$value.'</th>';
    }
   ?>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th>Number of errors</th>
   <?php 
    foreach ($array_3 as $key => $value) {
     echo '<th>'.$value.'</th>';
    }
   ?>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th>Time of response</th>
   <?php 
    // Moyenne des temps de réponse puis arrondir à 4 chiffres
    foreach ($array_4 as $key => $value) {
     echo '<th>'. round(array_sum($value) / count($value), 4) .'</th>';
    }
   ?>
  </tr>
 </table>
@endfor
```

It's it working fine but what I want is to create table which have values of $array_1, $array_2, $array_3 and $array_4 from 0 to 5 then 6 to 11 etc... like that :

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Key 0</th>
    <th>Key 1</th>
    <th>Key 2</th>
    <th>Key 3</th>
    <th>Key 4</th>
    <th>Key 5</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Value 0</th>
    <th>Value 1</th>
    <th>Value 2</th>
    <th>Value 3</th>
    <th>Value 4</th>
    <th>Value 5</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Value 0</th>
    <th>Value 1</th>
    <th>Value 2</th>
    <th>Value 3</th>
    <th>Value 4</th>
    <th>Value 5</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Value 0</th>
    <th>Value 1</th>
    <th>Value 2</th>
    <th>Value 3</th>
    <th>Value 4</th>
    <th>Value 5</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Value 0</th>
    <th>Value 1</th>
    <th>Value 2</th>
    <th>Value 3</th>
    <th>Value 4</th>
    <th>Value 5</th>
  </tr>
</table>

And then 

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Key 6</th>
    <th>Key 7</th>
    <th>Key 8</th>
    <th>Key 9</th>
    <th>Key 10</th>
    <th>Key 11</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Value 6</th>
    <th>Value 7</th>
    <th>Value 8</th>
    <th>Value 9</th>
    <th>Value 10</th>
    <th>Value 11</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Value 6</th>
    <th>Value 7</th>
    <th>Value 8</th>
    <th>Value 9</th>
    <th>Value 10</th>
    <th>Value 11</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Value 6</th>
    <th>Value 7</th>
    <th>Value 8</th>
    <th>Value 9</th>
    <th>Value 10</th>
    <th>Value 11</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Value 6</th>
    <th>Value 7</th>
    <th>Value 8</th>
    <th>Value 9</th>
    <th>Value 10</th>
    <th>Value 11</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

An array can have 5 values as it can have 28 values or 15 values, depends on how data it have.

What I've tried at least :
I've tried to make a php count function of an array to determine the number of values of it
Then I did php ceil function on it

```
ceil(count($array_1));
```

To make a loop like that with array_slice function to have an array_slice of $array1, 0, 5 then 6, 11.

But I'm really confused, I'm getting lost in all this code, is there a better way than what I'm currently doing?

Comment: You can start your loop from 0 to 4 and in another table you can from 5 to 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be using `array_chunk` to divide your array into the amount you need.

for example:

```
$Chunked = array_chunk($my_array['functions'], 5);

foreach ($Chunked as $Group ) {
    echo '<table>';
    foreach ($Group as $data) {
        echo '<tr>';
        foreach ($data as $k => $v) {
            echo '<th>'.$k.'</th>';
            echo '<td>'.$v.'</td>';
        }
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
}
```

Check the documentation for more information: http://php.net/array_chunk

Answer (score 0):

Using 2 nested `for` loops you can achieve this easily:

```
// The number of item you want per row
$column_count = 5;

echo '<table>';

// each iteration will build a row
for ($i = 0; $i < count($my_array); $i += $column_count) {
    echo '<tr>';

    // Write the cells
    for ($j = 0; $j < $column_count; $j += 1) {
        // Verify if the calculated index exists
        if (isset($my_array[$i + $j])) {
            echo '<td>' . $my_array[$i + $j]['my_data'] . '</td>';
        } else {
            echo '<td></td>';
        }
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```